# Is it possible to make Ubuntu always responsive?

Tags: configuration, memory-usage, cpu-load, responsiveness, scheduler

I have been with Ubuntu for over 10 years and I have installed and used it on machines ranging from low-end laptops through mining rigs to i7, 8Gb RAM desktop computers. And on every single combination I regularly experienced the desktop becoming unresponsive and the only thing I am left with is to push the proverbial pillow to the face of my suffering computer.

Even now, if I run an audacious enough npm build, or an ambitious video rendering, heck even if I open too many Chrome tabs, I can reliably put my system to ice.

My question is driven by a genuine curiosity and pure self interest. I would like to know:

**1. If there are some legacy Ubuntu-specific or Linux-specific reasons it is not possible to make the desktop always responsive even if all else fails.**

Even if there are 10000 processes trying to write to disk, 10000 processes each asking for a gigabyte of memory, 10000 processes that are in an infinite loop, the desktop should still be able to assume the position of the communist militia and take whatever resources he needs from the poor proletariat to keep on being responsive.

Is there something inherent to Linux that prevents distros such as Ubuntu from guaranteeing responsiveness, or would this be so difficult to accomplish as to make the gains not worth the expense?

**2. Can I configure Ubuntu to take whatever resources it needs, just to keep on marching no matter what?**

Is there any practical way to do this, even if the petite bourgeoisie and the proletariat have to suffer?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask page](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: This site works best when you ask a specific question and present factual data that can be analyzed by those standing by ready to help answer the specific question. For example, you mention Chrome but not the output from `Shift` + `Esc` nor common programs `free -h` nor `top`. No mention of OOM-Killer...

Comment: @thomasrutter Thank you for your suggestions. However, I have thought about my question for several months and my research turned out mostly techniques to deal with an already frozen system. The guidelines say "If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer." I take this at face value and want an answer that will give me the bird's eye view of the problem. I am not interested in solving the problem in each small domain individually (Chrome, npm...)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thank you for your advice. However, in this specific instance I want to use this site in the less than optimal manner, willing to pay the price it entails. I am not particularly mad at Chrome, and you mention some neat techniques to cope with an already struggling system, for which I am grateful. However, I would like a big picture answer on why such techniques are even needed.

Comment: Please, can someone explain how a Yes-No question, limited to the problem of responsiveness of one component, is considered "too broad"?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik There are many questions being asked in your question.  If you only wanted an answer to one part, you could edit it down to include only the part you want answered.  I know you were merely being facetious about the yes-no part - if you literally were only asking a yes-no question it would also not be suitable for this site.  But as it is, there are a lot of different directions the question is going in.

Comment: Edit your question and please describe the cpu/memory/swap of the COMPUTER THAT YOU'RE HAVING PROBLEM WITH. What is the output of `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness`? Report back to @heynnema. Please rewrite your question and remove the "colorful" language about communist militia, and petite bourgeoisie and the proletariat. Ask a single question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the problems you are describing at some times. Usually when I am compiling large projects using all my cores while also trying to do things like watch high resolution streaming video. Most of the time this problem can be split into two categories:

- The CPU is so busy that doing even the most basic video tasks cannot occur or occurs so slowly it's not usable, eg. no frames are updated. This could be improved by setting `x11`, `kwin`, and `plasmashell` (`mutter` and `gnome-shell` on Gnome systems respectively) to higher priorities since they do appear to default to `0` niceness - meaning they are competing against everything else for a slice of processor time.
- Memory usage has increased to the point that swap is being used. There is much debate about if swap is useful in modern desktop Linux since once used it often degrades performance to the point that the system becomes unusable. Some (including RedHat) argue there is good reason to disable swap entirely and in memory pressured scenarios rely on the Out of Memory (OOM) killer to regain control of a system.

You can experiment with different IO schedulers, but they will likely not make much difference. Since the implementation of the Completely Fair Queuing (CFQ) these issues are less about the scheduling and more about the actual speed of the disk. You can run this command to check what scheduler you are using:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
noop deadline [cfq]
```

It prints all the available schedulers and surrounds the currently active scheduler with brackets.

Disabling swap will likely "solve" your problem, but can ruin your experience in cases where for a very short time swap is needed like for doing a compute task that doesn't last long but requires lots of memory.

It may be useful to find or create a program that checks system responsiveness and disables swap when a system has lost control for too long.

Comment: Lots of prose, but does this really provide a solution/answer to the question?

Comment: Which part of the answer do you believe fails to answer the question?

Comment: It's very broad, and doesn't provide a specific set of steps for the user to follow to actually fix their problem. **How** do you set processes to higher priorities? For memory/swap issues, you don't discuss **vm.swappiness** settings. And "It may be useful to find or **create a program** that checks system responsiveness and disables swap when a system has lost control for too long."... you expect the user to be able to do that? Why not give a code example?

Comment: a.) I think the user understands how to modify process niceness, it's not a complex task and not all answers have to be step-by-step guides b.) I don't believe vm.swapiness is the solution (for reasons described in the answer) - you are welcome to submit your own answer related to swapiness if you think that's a solution. c.) Creating a program/script to do this isn't that complex and could be done in bash with a while loop. Such a program may already exist I have not researched it. You are welcome to submit your own answer.